# Is auto post back in ASP.net and AJAX are the same?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Is auto post back in ASP.net and AJAX are the same??? I want to send data to server and store that data in XML file without refreshing the page. I dont want to use ajax.. If there is any other way to do this with plain javascript then do let me know... thanks in advance...

Comment: If u want to send any data to server without refreshing the page use Ajax methods.You need to create XMLHttpObject and check its ReadyState to know abt the current status of operation.pls refer http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Is auto post back in ASP.net and AJAX are the same???
```

Not from a users perspective. When doing a postback, the user will see his entire page getting refreshed. When using AJAX, the user will not see his page get refreshed

```
I want to send data to server and store that data in XML file without 
refreshing the page. I dont want to use ajax.. If there is any other way
to do this with plain javascript
```

If you want to interact with the server without refreshing the page, you have to use AJAX.

**Note**: You may be confusing AJAX with the various AJAX controls / libraries like AjaxControlToolKit etc. If that is the case, then you can definitely use AJAX without using any of the libraries / controls. That is done by using the `XMLHTTPRequest` and `XMLHTTPResponse` objects directly via Javascript. However, that in itself is AJAX. Sample code of how to do it can be seen in this [page](http://swik.net/Ajax/How+to+use+XMLHttpRequest)

So, atleast as far as i know, you need to use AJAX to go to the server without appearing to the user that your page has gotten refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

as InSane said PostBack is quite different in AJAX and asp.net. AJAX mostly use Partial postback using XMLHTTPRequest Objects while full page postback sends complete Page's data to server resulting in complete page recycle.

For Your second question.. if you don't want to postback and still want to send some data to server there is only one way to do this by AJAX. AJAX in javascript is quite obscure i'll prefer using some javascript library like JQuery. Here is a link that shows how to call WebMethod on an ASPX page from JQuery.
http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Hope this will help.

Regards.